# node js tls1.2 and authentication

Tags: node.js

Is there any sample code out there for https server using a `SSLCertificateFile`  and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` authenticate with tls 1.2?

Any pointers to relevant samples would be highly appreciated.

ssllabs states it is vulnerable to DoS because it supports client-initiated renegotiation

and i can't get fusker's to create an ssl server

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var fusker = require('fusker');

//var server = fusker.https.createServer(443);
//var io = fusker.socket.listen(server);

var options = {
key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/server.key'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/mathpdq.crt'),
ciphers: 'RC4-SHA:RC4:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-SHA:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH:!AESGCM',
honorCipherOrder: true
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200);
res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(443);
```

Comment: Are you having a problem running any kind of https server, or are you having trouble just with TLS 1.2 specifically?  What version of Node are you running?

Comment: before i throw my hat into node.js i am wondering is it worth it cuz there is so much php code and apache is deep. why reinvent the wheel

Comment: apache 2.2 is vulnerable to crime attack and i am wondering if tls 1.2 is avail with node to block it

Comment: Creating a https listener is easy: http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener but it's not clear whether you have specific issues creating one with TLS 1.2.  Recent node builds against a new enough version of OpenSSL to pick up their 1.2 support.

Comment: @joe modified code above. connecting via tls 1.0

Comment: What are you using as a client?

Comment: https://secure.mathpdq.com/                  chrome

Comment: I believe you need both the `ciphers` and `honorCipherOrder` options as described here: http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html (though these options work with https.createServer also)

Comment: https://github.com/wearefractal/Fusker

Comment: @Joe that said I can't get it to work in https

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating a https listener is easy but it's not clear whether you have specific issues creating one with TLS 1.2. Recent node builds against a new enough version of OpenSSL to pick up their 1.2 support.

Then you need both the ciphers and honorCipherOrder options as described here: http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html

e.g

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('my.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('my.crt'),
    ciphers: 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH:!AESGCM',
    honorCipherOrder: true
};

var server = https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
    ...});

server.listen(443);
```

Comment: thx. https://secure.mathpdq.com/  reports as TLS1.0 and ssllabs says it is vulnerable to  DoS because it supports client-initiated renegotiation

Comment: i tweaked my question slightly above.