# node.js client with TLS1.2 support

Tags: windows, node.js

I want to write an HTTPS Client with TLS 1.2 support. How to enable this with my code (but default it is using TLS 1.0).

```
var https = require('https'); 
var util = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');
var options ={host: '192.168.1.85',port: 443,method: 'POST',
                                                 secureProtocol:'TLSv1_method'};
var request = https.request(options,responsehandle);
    
    request.send()
```

I am using nodejs version v0.10.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use a specific TLS version with \`node-fetch\` like TLS v1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77207601/how-do-i-use-a-specific-tls-version-with-node-fetch-like-tls-v1-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on some research I did both on Node.js documentation and SO, this sources might be useful for resolving your question. Both, in sort of a mix, can achieve what you want to do.

Node.js [HTTPS Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html)

Node.js [TLS Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html)

More into the specific issue, i found this question which is the same yours... [node js tls1.2 and authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434679/node-js-tls1-2-and-authentication)

Comment: I already saw all the link before asking this question. The nodejs documentation does not mentioned anything about TLS 1.2, by default it support TLS 1.0. The "node js tls1.2 and authentication", link is for creating a server with TLS 1.2. I wan to write a HTTPS client. Any way thanks..

Comment: What if you, on your client, use the cipher specified on the server setup? ( `var options = {
...
ciphers: 'RC4-SHA:RC4:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-SHA:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH:!AESGCM'
...
};` (instead of/combining it) with the secureProtocol option?

Comment: Actually I want to write a TLS1.2 client tool to test SSL server. Its the first step for the tool.. SO cipher suite wont be a problem and any way all SSL servers check the cipher suite priority and choose the one present in the server. So i dont think its a problem..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`tls`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html) library to do it.

```
const tls = require('tls');

tls.DEFAULT_MIN_VERSION = 'TLSv1.2';
```