# How do I use a specific TLS version with `node-fetch` like TLS v1.2?

Tags: node.js, node-fetch

I'm getting a 403 FORBIDDEN error and need to set the TLS version to `TLS v1.2` with fetch calls using the `node-fetch` library.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

You can use the [`tls`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html) library to do it.

```
const tls = require('tls');

tls.DEFAULT_MIN_VERSION = 'TLSv1.2';

const response = await fetch(...);
...
```